# Using "require" inside a Web Worker in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, web-worker

what i am trying to achieve is to import an npm module inside my React Web Worker using `require('package-name')`.

But it gives me the following error `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: require is not defined`
How can i use a module inside a worker, is there a native way or some way to bypass it?

Comment: Maybe this will help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-js-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined

Comment: You can either bundle the code that runs in the worker with a bundler like webpack or rollup, or you can use `importScripts` ([see this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts)). There are also ModuleWorkers, although they don't currently work properly even in chrome and I'll believe them when I see them.